# Does $f$ love $h$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$f, g$ are real functions and $A^f_g = \{ x\in \mathbb R : f(x) < g(x) \}$. We will call $f$ loves $g$ if for every $x \in A^f_g  $ , we will get a $y$ in $A^f_g  $  such that $f(y) < g(y)$  and $x < y$.

Now I have to prove or disprove that if $f $ loves $g$ and $g $ loves $h$  , then $f $ loves $h$ .

**My attempt:**   [image]

Can anyone please check my attempt ?

Comment: Alas, seems that this love is transitory (or is it transitive?)

Comment: $f$ loves $h$ because $A^f_g=\{\}$, and the definition is trivially true for the empty set. Also, note that the empty set is open (hint).

Comment: I also was thinking so. Can you please give a formal proof of this statement? @njw

Comment: $-1$ for the unhelpful title and another $-1$ for eyestrain.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a bad idea, but it doesn’t work, because when $A_g^f=\varnothing$ it is vacuously true that $f$ loves $g$. The only way to have $f$ not love $g$ is to ensure that $A_g^f$ has a maximum element. See if this is enough to let you come up with a counterexample; if not, I’ve left one in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-1,&\text{if }x\le 0\\1,&\text{if }x>0\,,\end{cases}$$ let $h(x)\equiv0$, and let $g(x)=x-2$.